# Rails w/ Vue.js AJAX form knows to use CSRF token?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am mounting a new Vue instance to an element that has some input fields bound to a 'user' data key. Clicking a button on this 'form' triggers the following Ajax request:

```
submit_user_form: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/users',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { user: this.user },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log(`errored out with ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                this.errors = err.responseJSON.errors
            }
        })
    }
```

Observing the header of the request generated by this Ajax code, I am noticing that it contains an `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header key.. Is this the default behavior for Vue.js? I would have thought I'd have to specify that as part of the request.

I suppose doing it this style (rendering pages with Vue scripts on them) isn't really all that different than using JQuery with turbolinks.. so I probably shouldn't take on the extra weight?

Sorry for the noob question -- I am generally confused about what technology I'm using here and what's integrating with what.

Comment: why just not use `remote: true` option. Extra source: https://codediode.io/lessons/1904-ajaxified-one-page-application-with-rails

Comment: Hm, so to avoid using the methods for rendering html? If that was the case, I would probably be using the SPA model with front-end routes.. It makes sense, I'll probably go that way in the end. Still, I am curious to explore what can be gained/lost from integrating Vue with Rails' normal rendering.